# I am trying to import data into jupyter note book from a URL but I am getting syntax errors stated below

Tags: url, import, jupyter

```
from pyodide.http import pyfetch

async def download(https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/autos/imports-85 data, "auto.csv"):
    response = await pyfetch( https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/autos/imports-85 data)
    if response.status == 200:
        with open("auto.csv", "wb") as f:
            f.write(await response.bytes())
```

When I run this code in my jupyter notebook I get the following error:

```
Cell In[28], line 3
async def download(https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/autos/imports-85 data, "auto.csv"):
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Could anyone tell what is the reason and how could it be corrected ?

I installed "pip install pyopenssl" in addition to importing libraries of Panda and Numpy but I keep getting syntax errors.

Comment: Jupyter runs a lot of language kernels and so ideally you'd say what that is in the post or tags. It seems you are trying to run Python using pyscript and so pyodide is the underlying kernel. As for your specific issue, you aren't including a workable URL. It ends in `-85 data`? Along that line, please read about posting 'fenced code blocks' on StackOverflow [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/8508004) so your code comes through as readable and useable. Does it work with a full Python kernel? Did you try your code on the Python console before converting it to pyscript?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work, or at least not on the StackOverflow system that allows snippets to be run here, but based on other information and another CSV file working with same approach, your mileage may vary.

---

The correct link is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54987484/how-to-get-text-objects-to-work-with-sklearn-classifier-pipeline#comment96757129_54987484):

It is:

```
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/autos/imports-85.data
```

I'm not sure what your pyfetch code is based on because it is **impossible** to read the way you shared it.

Good example, your URL isn't even coming through correct and instead of checking, you just left the post as is

The adapted code [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76148659/8508004) trying to apply it to yours is:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#0072b5" />
    <meta name="name" content="CSV Getting Demo adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/76148659/8508004" />

    <title>CSV Getting Demo with ML Data</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./favicon.png" />
    <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css"
    />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/examples/assets/css/examples.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="pandas-output" hidden>
        <h3>Output</h3>
        <div id="pandas-output-inner"></div>
    </div>
    <py-tutor>
            <py-config>
packages = [
    "numpy",
    "pandas",
    "jinja2"
]
[[fetch]]
from = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/autos/imports-85.data'
</py-config>

<py-script>
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('imports-85.data')
Element("pandas-output").element.style.display = "block"
display (df.head().style.format(precision=2), target="pandas-output-inner", append="False")
</py-script>
        </py-tutor>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

It doesn't work though running the code here on StackOverflow and I'm not on a reasonable computer to check why or do developing elsewhere to try. At first I thought it may be something similar to the CORS issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76069710/retrieving-csv-file-from-url#comment134320337_76148659), but VMAtm says his approach works and so I think the one by Jeff Glass, who works on Pyscript should also work since it works when I use a CSV file stored at GitHub, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76148659/8508004).

The easiest thing is to start with a CSV that works with pyfetch then you can eliminate that as an issue. The examples [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76148659/8508004) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76074686/8508004) work to get the `turtles.csv` I know works. The latter one you can even see work by running the snipper in Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You have a small typo in your code. These things should be fixed:

1. Find the correct link, as @Wayne mentioned: `https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/autos/imports-85.data` instead of `https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/autos/imports-85 data` (note the point)
2. You need to define your function with parameters names, and not values. As you know the exact url, you can provide it with hard-code, or can use a parameter if other `url` will be used too
3. You need to wrap strings in `'` or `"`
4. `"auto.csv"` is the name of the file you want to save your data to, so, again, you can hard-code it, or create a parameter for your function

So, your code can be like this:

```
from pyodide.http import pyfetch

async def download():
    response = await pyfetch("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/autos/imports-85.data")
    if response.status == 200:
        with open("auto.csv", "wb") as f:
            f.write(await response.bytes())

data = await download()
```

or like this:

```
from pyodide.http import pyfetch

async def download(url, target_file_path):
    response = await pyfetch(url)
    if response.status == 200:
        with open(target_file_path, "wb") as f:
            f.write(await response.bytes())

data_url = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/autos/imports-85.data"
data_result_path = "auto.csv"
data = await download(data_url, data_result_path)
```

Comment: My question though is does this work in your hands? I tried removing the `[[fetch]]` portion I had based on [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76148659/8508004) adding your code to the HTML I had tried in mine and it didn't seem to fix things because still nothing displays when I run the code on StackOverflow. By way of comparison, if I go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76074686/8508004) and edit my old answer to add in [the code supplied by Jeff Glass here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76148659/8508004) it works in the edit form launching that snippet in the SO interface.

Comment: What exactly you expect to be visible? This code downloads the file, and saves it locally. Do you need to read it after?

Comment: Pandas should be able to read the `auto.csv`? If you go to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76074686/8508004) and press 'Run Code Snippet' there you can see the first five rows of the dataframe viewed. I was looking to do that. My code in this thread is based on using `[[fetch]]` the way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76148659/8508004) uses it. The code from there pasted into that edited snippet also works to show the dataframe. However, I cannot those approaches to work with the URL you and I use. So I'm asking if you really see your code working because I don't? I'm trying to ...

Comment: <continued> read the data in with Pandas and show it as proof it worked. But it doesn't work with any of the approaches I tried. So to put it simply I'm asking if you actually tried your code and can get the data?

Comment: @Wayne Yes, I have. However, I can't see the advantages of using `pyodide` for this, as this can be done easily in Notebook without this package

Comment: I still am baffled why I cannot seem to get the snippet running system to get this data in StackOverflow but maybe github is allowed by SO and that other site isn't. I didn't bother making any real web page beside that to test it further. ... As to everything after 'However' in your last comment: Yes, indeed. I totally agree it is so much easier to do this in a full Python kernel than in pyodide.